# Pandas: Resample a dataframe given a list of indexes that are not evenly spaces

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe `df: pd.Dataframe` and a subset `selected_indexes` of indexes from `df.index` how can I resample df with the `max` operator applied to each interval `selected_indexes[i], selected_indexes[i+1]` ?

For example, given a dataframe:

```
   col
0    5
1    0
2    3
3    3
4    7
5    9
6    3
7    5
8    2
9    4
```

And a selection of index "selected_indexes = [0, 5, 6, 9]" and applying the maximum on the `col` column between each interval (assuming we keep the end point and exclude the starting point), we should get:

```
   col
0    5
5    9
6    3
9    5
```

For example the line `9` was made with `max(5, 2, 4)` from lines `7, 8, 9 \in (6, 9]`.

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example and the matching expected output to clarify what you need exactly

Comment: The logic is still unclear, why you keep 3 but change 4 to 5?

Comment: Check if my updated answer is what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### new interpretation

```
selected_indexes = [0, 5, 6, 9]
group = (df.index.to_series().shift() # make groups
           .isin(selected_indexes)    # based on
           .cumsum()                  # previous indices
        )

# get max per group
out = df.groupby(group).max().set_axis(selected_indexes)

# or for many aggregations (see comments):
out = (df.groupby(group).agg({'col1': 'max', 'col2': 'min'})
         .set_axis(selected_indexes)
       )
```

Output:

```
   col
0    5
5    9
6    3
9    5
```

##### previous interpretation of the question

You likely need a [`rolling.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.max.html), not resample:

```
out = df.loc[selected_indexes].rolling(3, center=True).max()
```

Or, if you want the ±1 to apply to the data **before** selection:

```
out = df.rolling(3, center=True).max().loc[selected_indexes]
```

Example:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)})
selected_indexes = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]

print(df)

   col
0    5
1    0
2    3
3    3
4    7
5    9
6    3
7    5
8    2
9    4


out = df.loc[selected_indexes].rolling(3, center=True).max()
print(out)

   col
1  NaN
2  3.0
3  9.0
5  9.0
6  9.0
8  4.0
9  NaN

out2 = df.rolling(3, center=True).max().loc[selected_indexes]
print(out2)

   col
1  5.0
2  3.0
3  7.0
5  9.0
6  9.0
8  5.0
9  NaN
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. When you apply the max to "4" for line 9, you should get 4. When you apply the max for 8, since its the interval (6, 8] you should get max(5, 2) which is 5.

Comment: @Jeremy that's why you must provide a meaningful example and the matching expected output (ideally breaking down one or two examples of calculation). **My interpretation** of your question is not necessarily what you want ;)

Comment: @mozaway You are right, I edited and tried to be a little bit more explicite.

Comment: @mozaway Thanks you. I think it is going to work. :) Do you have a way to apply a specific operator per column ? like `{'col1':max, 'col2':min}` ?

Comment: use `.agg({'col1': 'max', 'col2': 'min'})`

Comment: @mozaway Thanks you very much. It seams to work perfectly. You may want to add the `agg` example in your answer too as this may be useful for other people (I picked max as a simplified example).

Comment: Little extra: if the first index insn't in the select_index, you probably want to use `group.dropna()`.